# Eclipse getting not restarted and DDMS issue

Tags: android, eclipse

Before down voters give a down vote i am telling you that i have already checked all the answers on stack overflow for my issue but none of them has helped to me. So please if you have any other solution then give me a solution rather than a down vote.

Firstly , I am using latest `ADT` Bundle and started my eclipse. On the start up of eclipse i am getting the error `" Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700). Make sure you do not have another instance of DDMS or of the eclipse plugin running. If it's being used by something else, choose a new port number in the preferences."`

For that i have seen all the links and solutions but none of them working. I `restart adb` , `kill adb`, restarted my system too.

Also i have found strange when i saw in task manager i m getting two `eclipse.exe` files and when i exited from my eclipse none of them `exe` file ended. Even i am not able to restart my eclipse. When i restarted my eclipse it didn't.

So please if any one have faced this kind if weird issue then give your suggestion. Any help would be appreciated !!!

Comment: Have you tried deleting this eclipse and getting a fresh one ?

Comment: This is my latest one !!!

Comment: If nothing works, try clearing Eclipse's settings. To do that, just rename or delete your curren't workspace.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your PC? I think there are two versions of eclipse running and they are conflicting at port 8700. I usually see this message when I am running both Android studio and Eclipse.

Comment: I have mentioned that i have restarted my system too. And I am using 64 bit eclipse. And yes there is AS in my system but i never opened it.

Comment: I am very sure that there are two versions running that is creating the conflict, kill one of them and try.

Comment: I already told about down vote. Downvoters give me a solution and reason!!

Comment: You must also check if the DDMS is running separately than your eclipse. For that matter, any other component. This should ideally have been resolved as soon as you restarted your PC, but I wonder how and what is causing two instances to load. It would be helpful if you let us know about the OS you are working on?

Comment: Yes i am confused for that why its showing two eclipse.exe files?

Comment: Its a window 7......

Comment: @PiyushGupta have you tried my suggestion? Any success or difference it made?

Comment: I have tried that way but didn't get success. Though  i have posted my answer.

Comment: Don't use Eclipse if you don't like wasting your time. AS is much stable :P

Comment: Yes i will switch to AS ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

OMG !!!

There are no any conflict of eclipse. Started eclipse and ended `eclipse.exe` file five times.

Finally restarted my system five times solved my issue !!!

Comment: So, you can avoid switching to AS... ;)

Comment: No .. No nothing like that. My current app is in eclipse so i can't take a change with AS.

Comment: But you said: `Yes i will switch to AS ASAP.`

Comment: Yes. but AS is too much stable rather than eclipse. So

Comment: Yes thats a true. But one drawback of AS is its sync system is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

1st make sure you have the correct host file setup which is located at,

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc

This should contain this line,

> 127.0.0.1 localhost

Next is to change the DDMS port. Which can be found here,

> Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS

- Set Base local debugger port to "8601"
- Check the box that says "Use ADBHOST" and the value should be "127.0.0.1"

Point to be noted,

1. Make sure you are trying to run DDMS twice.
2. You have told DDMS which VM you want to debug at localhost:8700. 
   To do so, go to the DDMS perspective and click on the system_process (or whatever process you want to debug).